# Why can't we vertically scale a system infinitely?

Tags: distributed-system, cpu, scaling

When talking about scaling a system, it's often said that vertical scaling has limitations. So after a point, we need to scale the system horizontally.

What are the limitations of:

1. Main memory - What is the maximum amount of memory supported by a 32bit and 64bit processor and why? Is it the width of the address bus and hence 2^32 and 2^64 is the max supported size?
2. Hard disk/SSD - Maximum storage that we can add to a system?
3. Network - Is it measured in requests per second that are supported? Number of connections? What is a typical load supported by modern day laptops with say i5/8GB/256GB SSD?

Comment: The CPU is a hard limitation, e.g. no models that go faster than 5GHz, no useful models with more than 64 cores. The other things are more like a matter of cost, e.g. you can horizontally scale storage independently by setting up a storage area network (SAN) that combines multiple disks as a RAID cluster, at a hardware cost of roughly $40k per Petabyte.

Comment: Askers on this site are expected to do some research on their own before asking, present what they found and describe why it did not suit their needs. So please edit your question, tell us what you found in your research on all these 3 points and why it did not answer your questions about it.

Comment: In regards to 3, are you suggesting running a web server on a laptop? The right choice of hardware is obviously step 1 in the vertical scaling process, and laptops are not the appropriate choice of hardware for a web server.

Comment: Have you ever seen a 4000000GHz CPU? How about a 4000000TB hard drive? Or a 4000000GB memory stick?

Comment: Basically: What problems do you think you would run into, if you were Google and you tried to do everything on one server?

Comment: We cannot to anything infinitely!

Answer (score 11):

**Vertical Scaling does have limitations.**

Those limitations are called Physics, and Engineering.

Turns out that Physics doesn't like performing to much work in a single place, and our current engineering skills can only squeeze so much useful work in before it becomes useless noise.

As for current performance:

- You could go and look up the benchmarks for the various systems you are looking at using.
- You could go even further and compare across a benchmark with a similar workload to the workload you have in mind.

Answers to your direct points:

1. Stupid answer: In the year 2020 somewhere in the range of 64GB to 1TB based on specific hardware, could be more but that gets pricey fast.

- Non stupid answer:  `= Min(2 ^ bits in the pointer * number of system provided heaps, Max OS support Memory, Max supported Ram Module Size * Available Ram Slots)`

2. Stupid Answer: In the year 2020 a few to some Tera Bytes.

- Non-stupid answer:  `= Min(max file size in File system * Max number of files in file system * number of supported file systems, Max OS Support for File-system size, Number of available Drive Connection Ports * Max size of installable storage modules)`

3. Stupid Answer: 100 Giga Bits per Second. *Though you may be talking about application specific throughput in which case concurrent connections, or requests per second are better metrics.*

- Non-stupid answer: The slowest point in the network. This will probably be the Internet Link itself, or the application responding to network requests. Though it could easily be any of the intervening network devices.

Comment: Maximum storage can be larger if we allow multiple file systems. I’d be curious how much storage you can add to a MacBook with four USB slots if you plug a 7 port hub into each port, another 7 port hub into each of the ports in the hubs, and a raid drive into each of those ports. I guess there’s a point where it stops working.

Comment: The filesystem limit isn't usually the limit for storage. You can always make a filesystem with higher limits, anyway. I think the limit for storage in a single system is the point at which it stops being "one system". If the hard drives are in a different box in a different rack with its own power supply and connected by Ethernet, are they really part of the computer any more, or is it now horizontal scaling?

Comment: "bits in the pointer" - Should be "relevant bits in the pointer". Current 64-bit systems don't actually support 64 bits of address space. I think 48 bits of address space and 42 bits of actual physical RAM is supported on our current architectures.

Comment: All good points. @user253751 I agree that at some point a large system becomes difficult to describe as vertical or horizontal. The way I see it, the old iron-horses that take up an entire single building constituted a single Vertical system simply because the information crunching part was shared between all components. These days where processing can be off-loading onto TPUs, GPUs, and secondary CPUs - I feell I am justified in saying that modern computers come pre-horizontally scaled.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Even back in the day of 16bit pointers, many systems used the high 4-6 bits to store alternate information. I still remember the day of the LC II, it had 12MB of ram and the OS of the day could only address 10MB. There was a system extension that could be installed that turned the remaining 2MB into a RAM Disk. My analysis though was (Programming Environment, Operating System, Hardware) so while your point is accurate, its not a limitation of the programming language, but a limit imposed by either the OS itself, or a fundamental limitation enforced by the hardware.

Comment: Your third answer is missing a number in it. It should be maybe 100Gbps. I know I have a system with two 40Gbps cards (lucky eBay find) but (A) I'm not sure the CPU can generate that much data and (B) I don't have anything to connect it to besides itself.

Answer (score 1):

The need to Horizontally Scale a system mostly comes from the fact that you can. Vertical Scaling costs money. How much you get for your money is not liner. Eventually it costs more and more to get less and less improvement. Eventually you get more for your money by adding a second system (Horizontal Scaling) then you get spending that money improving the existing system (Vertical Scaling).

So even if you could infinitely Vertically Scale (you can't) you'd still hit the point where you're wasting money long before that.

Answer (score 0):

Because... there's only so fast that we can make one thing go.

**Memory** isn't likely to be a problem any time soon. But that's because memory is *already* horizontally scaled. You can always add more modules, or more chips on a module. You could have a room-sized or building-sized memory module.

*However*, room-sized memory will be slow because the speed of light takes quite a lot of nanoseconds to reach across the room. Better to have the memory near the CPU, so instead of one CPU room and then one giant memory room, we alternate: one CPU, a few memory sticks, another CPU, another few memory sticks, etc. And this is what you get when you have multiple servers.

We can always make pointers bigger if needed, that's no big problem. You'd need a new type of CPU, but if you've got a city block full of RAM then you can surely afford to pay Intel to create a 128-bit CPU.

Vertically-scaled memory would mean putting more bits in a chip, and we don't know how to make them that small, and we certainly can't make them smaller than atoms. But it's okay because memory already scales horizontally.

**Hard disk/SSD** - Same thing - it already scales horizontally! You can make circuit boards full of terabyte SSD chips, stack up the circuit boards into a big rack, multiply the racks to fill a room, fill up every room in the building. You can use software RAID to pretend it's one big drive.

Vertically-scaled HDDs/SSDs would mean putting more bits in a chip (or on a brown spinny thing), and we don't know how to make them that small, and we certainly can't make them smaller than atoms. But it's okay because drives already scale horizontally.

**Network** is measured in gigabits per second. We use optic fibers and modulate them on and off to achieve gigabits per connection. The limiting factor for vertical scaling is how fast we can turn the light on and off. We don't know how to make light turn on and off a trillion times a second, and it certainly can't be any faster than the frequency of the light wave.

Networks can scale horizontally, because you can put multiple fibers in a cable and connect them to multiple network cards.

But I think you forgot something. You want to have fifty quintillion bits per second coming into your network port, but you only have a 4GHz CPU to process those bits? **CPUs** are the real bottleneck because they have to do things in order. They *can't* pretend to scale vertically just by scaling horizontally. A 10-core CPU *cannot* pretend to be one CPU that's 10 times as fast. And if you're going to buy a 10000000-core CPU to process your fifty quintillion bits per second... at that point, why not buy 1000000 separate 10-core CPUs? They're much cheaper because everyone uses them, they're not a custom design just for you. Because it's faster to interleave things to reduce distance, a 10000000-core CPU would probably be designed like a rack of servers anyway. May as well just buy a rack of separate servers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the factors already mentioned there's another biggie involved:  Heat.

Look at your CPU and memory--nope, what you're looking at is the packaging, not the devices.  The devices are a lot smaller.  We put them in big boxes to make connections more feasible **and to provide large contact surfaces for cooling**.

We could put almost everything in a typical computer into a package no larger than the CPU--but there's no way we could keep it from burning itself up.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 fundamental problems:

- contention
- coherence

All other problems can be placed in these categories.

For more information about scalability, look for the Universal Scalability Law (which includes Amdahl's Law) which is expressed in terms of contention and coherence.